# rails, devise recoverable not sending emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, passwords

i have devise set up in my rails app. i added confirmable, and have emails sent to confirm email accounts and it is sending properly in development env.

i added the recoverable option as well:

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable
```

but when i go to the "forgot my password", and enter an email, it does not send anything. I'm really struggling trying to figure out why the recoverable email is not working. I'm pretty sure it's not my email settings because it works with confirmable. Can somebody provide any thoughts on debugging? or where to start looking into why recoverable is not working?

Thanks so much in advance.

my log when i press the submit button on forgot my password:

```
Started POST "/users/password" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-28 01:54:07 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by PasswordsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bGrcwyIqwkeC51TOLyoDqX1bTj2XKNH9RHU7qJ01Zfs=", "user"=>{"email"=>""}, "commit"=>"Reset Password"}
  Rendered devise/passwords/new.html.erb within layouts/application (8.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (4.2ms)
```

here is the log when i sign up a new user (confirmable):

```
 Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (1.4ms)

Devise::Mailer#confirmation_instructions: processed outbound mail in 33.6ms

Sent mail to test19@test.com (223.6ms)
Date: Fri, 28 Nov 2014 02:29:45 -0500
From: test
Reply-To: test
To: test19@test.com
Subject: Confirmation instructions
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

why doesn't recoverable activate the devise::mailer?

my User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username, use: [:slugged, :finders]

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    username_changed?
  end

  #validates :username, :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false},
  #:format => { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]+\Z/ }

  validates :firstname, presence: true
  validates :lastname, presence: true
  validates :country, presence: true
  validates :birthday, presence: true

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  attr_accessor :login

  validates_with AttachmentSizeValidator, :attributes => :avatar, :less_than => 1.megabytes

  acts_as_voter
  acts_as_messageable
  acts_as_votable
  is_impressionable

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { 
      :medium => "300x300>", 
      :thumb => "100x100#", 
      :small => "50x50#",
      :tiny => "35x35>",
      :header => "30x30#" }, 
      default_url: ActionController::Base.helpers.image_path('silhouette.png')

  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

   def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
      conditions = warden_conditions.dup
      if login = conditions.delete(:login)
        where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
      else
        where(conditions).first
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you send a back trace/server log while you are requesting a send password reset instruction ? A log can help me to help you fixing your problem

Comment: sure - i just posted what i see in my console when i hit the submit button. thanks for your help - let me know anything else you need to see.

Comment: brother, its a very little portion to be honest. But if you wait a little bit you will see the email messages displayed in your console. You need to give more details server log :)

Comment: hmm thanks rubyrider. i just checked the logs, and what i posted is literally the only thing that is happening when i hit the submit button... it's not calling devise::mailer at all.... would you happen to know where this is called?

Answer (score 1):

Have you added proper fields required for recoverable module in the users table? If not, then run this migration

```
class AddRecoverableToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :reset_password_token, :string
    add_column :users, :reset_password_sent_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

After running this, restart the server and try again

Or, inside `form_for` tag in `devise/password/new.html.erb` add these lines, you will get the exact errors on your view

```
<% if f.object.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
    <% f.object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

So, as your `username` field is creating problem, you can add a `before_update` callback, try this

```
before_validation :check_for_reset_token, if: Proc.new{ |user| user.reset_password_token_changed? }

def check_for_reset_token
  self.username = username
end
```

Comment: hi RSB - yes, i have these fields in my users table already. i'm just not sure why it is not calling the mailer when a user hits submit?

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: yes, several times. everytime i hit submit, it just renders what i posted in my original question.

Comment: What it says when you enter the email to recover?

Comment: nothing - it simply refreshes to the same page. the URL changes from http://localhost:3000/users/password/new to http://localhost:3000/users/password after submit

Comment: I got it, there's some error, are you sure you enter an email which is already there in the users table?

Comment: yes - confirmed that i am entering an email that exists in the users table.

Comment: ahhhh so smart, RSB! error came up and said 'username can't be blank' - why is devise asking for username? can i disable this?

Comment: Remove username validation from user model, this is happening because the username of the the user for whom you are trying to recover the  password is blank, either add username manually from the console, or remove the validation

Comment: hmm i removed the username validation but the error still comes up. and i checked that the user does have a username in the table. is it because i'm not including that field in the form? i'm so confused why devise would even check for this?

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure, can you confirm these steps:

Confirm that you have this in your config/environments/developement.rb

```
   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
   config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
   config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Can you double check that you uncommented all these lines when you ran the migration:

```
   t.string   :confirmation_token
   t.datetime :confirmed_at
   t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
   t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
```

I would also reccommend this in config/environments/developement.rb

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Comment: hi fresh - thanks. confirmed that i have all the top 3 lines in development.rb. my problem is with :recoverable, and not :confirmable. the problem is really odd because my :confirmable works perfectly fine, but :recoverable does not. =/